# Concatenate strings at the same indexes in two lists

Tags: python, string, list, python-2.7

I have two lists and I'd like to combine them following the same order.

Below is the question.

```
A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
B = ['10','11','12']
```

To get a new list such as below

```
A+B = ['1,2,3,10','4,5,6,11','7,8,9,12']
```

I try `extend`, `zip`, `append`, `enumerate` but could not get what I want. Two loops the result will repeat.

Any hint or elegant way to do this please?

Comment: So you want to extend the strings contained in list A with the strings of the second list B?

Answer (score 6):

`A` and `B` are lists of strings. Using `zip`, you can create pairs like `('1,2,3', '10')`. Afterwards you can combine these two strings using `join`.

```
A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
B = ['10','11','12']

C = [','.join(z) for z in zip(A, B)]
print C
```

Answer (score 5):

Just use `','.join` and `zip`..

```
A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
B = ['10','11','12']

C = [ ','.join(pair) for pair in zip(A,B) ]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
[a + ',' + b for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use `enumerate`, although `zip` is the more natural choice

```
>>> A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
>>> B = ['10','11','12']
>>> [a + "," + B[i] for i, a in enumerate(A)]
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12']
```

Answer (score 2):

Already answered, so here are some fun and games -should work if A and B are different lengths -zip leaves out unmatched stuff:

```
>>> A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
>>> B = ['10','11','12']

# basic solution using for/len, will except if len(A) > len(B)
>>> [ A[i] + "," + B[i] for i in range(len(A)) ]

# complicated solution to deal with a difference in the
# lengths of A and B 
>>> [ (A[i] if i < len(A) else ',,') + "," + (B[i] if i < len(B) else '') for i in range((len(A) if len(A)>=len(B) else len(B))) ]
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12']

# add something to A, len(A) > len(B)
>>> A.append('13,14,15')
>>> [ (A[i] if i < len(A) else ',,') + "," + (B[i] if i < len(B) else '') for i in range((len(A) if len(A)>=len(B) else len(B))) ]
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12', '13,14,15,']

# add a couple of things to B, len(B) > len(A)
>>> B.append('16')
>>> B.append('17')
>>> [ (A[i] if i < len(A) else ',,') + "," + (B[i] if i < len(B) else '') for i in range((len(A) if len(A)>=len(B) else len(B))) ]
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12', '13,14,15,16', ',,,17']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also `map` `str.join` after zipping:

```
A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
B = ['10','11','12']

from itertools import izip

print(map(",".join, izip(A, B)))
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12']
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this, assuming the two lists are of the same length:

```
def concat_lists(l1, l2):
    concat_list = []
    for i in range(len(l1)):
        concat_list.append(l1[i] + ',' + l2[i])
    return concat_list
```

Or using a list comprehension instead:

```
def concat_lists(l1, l2):
    return [l1[i] + ',' + l2[i] for i in range(len(l1))]
```

Answer (score 1):

By using `map` ...certainly this method won't create any extra `list` of `tuples` like `zip`..

```
>>> A = ['1,2,3','4,5,6','7,8,9']
>>> B = ['10','11','12']
>>> map(lambda x, y:x + ',' + y, A, B)
['1,2,3,10', '4,5,6,11', '7,8,9,12']
```

Comment: `zip` doesn't create an extra list of tuples either in python 3, and if you are really worried about it you can use `izip` in python 2.x from `itertools`.

Comment: @ChadS. I was referring to `Python2.7` and about `zip` only..and BTW itertools.izip (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) itself uses `map`

Comment: that's fine, I'd rather still use `izip` than map + lambda.

Comment: @ChadS.  what do you say for this? `izip() should only be used with unequal length inputs when you don’t care about trailing, unmatched values from the longer iterables`

Comment: @gsb-eng, `itertools.izip` does not use map,  the equivalent example  written in python uses map